# could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>=0) x86-mingw32'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run rails server, this shows up. I am in the right folder, and googled the error but still can't solve this problem

Error: could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>=0) x86-mingw32'

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember something like this. Try adding this to your gemfile:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

Edit: [More Info](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors)

Comment: it again gave men an error ;(( it says While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLine Error)  unknown command tzinfo-data,

Comment: Did you run `bundle`? Otherwise, it might help if add more detail to the question. What operating system are you using? What version of Ruby? What does you Gemfile look like? What steps did you take to get the error?

Comment: oh it was because I didnt download gems correctly: had to use curl http://installrails.com/update_rubygems.rb | ruby
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you should replace encoding like bottom under the file "C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\2.2.0\win32"

```
#LOCALE = Encoding.find(Encoding.locale_charmap)
LOCALE = Encoding::UTF_8
```